# Dynamically adding table row beside the first table row instead after the first table row using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I dont know why when I am trying to add a table row on my table.It only add beside the first table row instead after the first table row.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
          <th width="10%">Unit</th>
          <th width="30%">Item Description</th>
          <th width="10%">Stock No.</th>
          <th width="10%">Estimated Unit Cost</th>
          <th width="10%">Estimated Cost</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr class="wrap_inputs">
        <td><input type="numer" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="numer" name="unit[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_description[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="numer" name="stock_no[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="numer" name="eunitcost[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="numer" name="ecost[]" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>

     </table>
</div>
```

and my javascript to add table row is this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var max_fields      = 10;
var wrapper         = $(".wrap_inputs");
var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");

var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<tr>');
        $(wrapper).append('<td><input type="numer" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>');
        $(wrapper).append('<td><input type="numer" name="unit[]" class="form-control"></td>');
        $(wrapper).append('<td><input type="text" name="item_description[]" class="form-control"></td>');
        $(wrapper).append('<td><input type="numer" name="stock_no[]" class="form-control"></td>');
        $(wrapper).append('<td><input type="numer" name="eunitcost[]" class="form-control"></td>');
        $(wrapper).append('<td><input type="numer" name="ecost[]" class="form-control"></td>');
        $(wrapper).append('</tr>');
    }
else
{
  alert('You Reached the limits')
 }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
```

a screenshot of what is happening when i click the button to add a tablerow

[image: a]

what might I could gone wrong? On putting the `wrap_input` class or my javascript code?

Comment: if you append to **wrap_inputs** you add your code to the current line of your table

Comment: You need to append to the id **dataTables-example**

Comment: Adding to tr just adds a row to the row, you need to append it to the table and not to tr

Comment: @Inazo I tried append it to the table first it add a tablerow on after the first table row. And it doesnt look like the first table row, then when I add another(2nd time) it add besides the 2nd table row.

Comment: @Dinosan0908 I tried append it to the table first it add a tablerow on after the first table row. And it doesnt look like the first table row, then when I add another(2nd time) it add besides the 2nd table row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the new elements to the original table row by appending them to "wrap_inputs" which is in fact the first row so you're in a way nesting the appended row within the hardcoded one

try wrapping all rows with

```
<tbody id="wrap_inputs">
    ... your TR ...
</body>
```

this way, when appending childs to wrap_inputs you'll  be adding them to the table body and not the first row

Comment: Yes it does adds a table row, but why it doesn't look like with the first row?

Comment: looks like a styling/bootstrap issue... if the hardcoded tr element still has the class="wrap_inputs" tag and the new ones don't, then bootstrap will not style them in the same manner

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of this line `$(wrapper).append('<tr>')...;` Here `$(".wrap_inputs");` is a `tr` and this snippet `$(wrapper).append('<tr>')` will create another `tr` inside it.

Also note `wrapper` is a query object, you can avoid putting `$` before it and also avoid multiple append. Either you can do `.append("<tr><td>...</td></tr>)` or use use backtick to create string literal

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $("#dataTables-example tbody");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

  var x = 1;
  add_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      wrapper.append(`<tr>
  <td><input type="numer" name="quantity[]" class="form- control"></td>
  <td><input type="numer" name="unit[]" class="form-control"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="item_description[]" class="form-control"</td>   <td><input type="numer" name="stock_no[]" class="form-control"></td>
  <td><input type="numer" name="eunitcost[]" class="form-control"></td>
  <td><input type="numer" name="ecost[]" class="form-control"></td>
  </tr>`);
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
        <th width="10%">Unit</th>
        <th width="30%">Item Description</th>
        <th width="10%">Stock No.</th>
        <th width="10%">Estimated Unit Cost</th>
        <th width="10%">Estimated Cost</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="wrap_inputs">
        <td><input type="numer" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="numer" name="unit[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_description[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="numer" name="stock_no[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="numer" name="eunitcost[]" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="numer" name="ecost[]" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button type="button" class="add_form_field">Add</button>
```

Comment: I see, sir can I ask why Javier Larroulet's Answer solve my issue but every new table row had no styling like the first table row that I have?

Comment: oops when I try to avoid multiple append it's now the same with the first row. Thank you guys